# Plug-in for reserving rooms or equipment via corporate intranet

Tags: plugins, calendar, plugin-events-calendar

I'm setting up a corporate intranet for a small organization  of about 80 employees.  I'm using WordPress running on a Linux server internally.  I'd like to give users the ability to reserve conference rooms and audiovisual equipment via the intranet.  (I don't want to have them go in through the WP Dashboard.)

I recently bought the Premium version of http://onlinebookingcalendar.com/ , but I don't think it'll work for us.  There are a few issues with it.  First of all, it seems like overkill for what we need.  But the *main* problem is that other users can't see the name of the person who reserved the resource.  That information is fairly important for the functionality that we need.

I've spent some time Googling, and I just don't see anything that would work for this seemingly simple purpose.  I would really rather not pay for something that has a monthly subscription fee.  And, as I said, I don't want users to log into the dashboard part of WordPress.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

We are using Google apps/calendar at our work and it works nice. Would that be an option?

Comment: Jens, thanks for the tip.  Google Apps might be an option.  There is one problem with it, though -- it requires users to log in before they can use it.  I've noticed that logging in seems to be a big barrier with our users.